# Restlet not playing well with JSON on GAE

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, restlet

I am working on a Restlet Server on GAE.  SO far I have the urls running returning strings to the user.  Now I am implementing JSON into the application, I have added the org.json2.0 and org.restlet.ext.json jar files to the build path.  However, whenever I try using Json I always get a NoClassDef error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to add Jackson :

http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/28-restlet/299-restlet.html

That works fine for me.